# find the supremum of a set

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $0 < x < 1 $. Prove $s_n = \sum_{k=1}^n x^k $is bounded and find $\sup \{ s_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $.

#### Atempt

We have that $0 < x < 1 \implies x^k < 1 $ since otherwise $x^k - 1 = (x-1)(1+x+..+x^{k-1}) > 0$ and so $x > 1 $ contradiction. Therefore by the triangle ineqaulity,

$$ \Big| \sum_{k=1}^n x^k \Big| \leq \sum |x^k| < 1 + 1 + ... + 1 = n$$
But, I guess this is not good enough. I cant see to find a bound for this sequence. For the second part, since $( s_n)$ is non decreasing ,we have

$$ \sup (s_n) = \lim s_n = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} x^k = \frac{1}{x-1} $$

is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified what is fixed and what you are taking the sup over. If the sup is over $x$ and you want a sup value for each $n$, then the sup is exactly $n$. Otherwise the sup is $1/(1-x)$ if the $x$ value is fixed and the sup is over all $n$. As far as bounding the partial sums, $1/(1-x)$ is indeed a bound, for $0 < x < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

The partial sums form a monotonically increasing sequence which had a limit, and therefore, must be bounded.